# Do questions about Discord belong on Super User or Web Applications?

Tags: discussion, migration, on-topic

[discord](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/discord) is a voice and text chat program similar to Skype and Teamviewer. It's available both as a downloadable desktop application for Windows/Mac/Linux, and as an in-browser Web Application.

My recent question [How do @everyone and @here work? What's the difference between them?](https://superuser.com/questions/1212953/how-do-everyone-and-here-work-whats-the-difference-between-them/1212954#1212954) currently has 2 votes to close the question as off-topic, stating it should be migrated to [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

[image: Migration votes for Web Apps]

This seems strange to me. From personal experience, most people use Discord as a desktop application. Just because Discord happens to also have a web version available shouldn't make it off topic. [Skype for Web](https://web.skype.com/) also exists, but that doesn't make Skype questions off-topic.

Humorously, when the question "[How can I add a custom emoji to my Discord server?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/105224/revisions)" was asked on Web Apps, the question was closed as off topic and [migrated here to Super User.](https://superuser.com/questions/1200293/how-can-i-add-custom-emoji-to-my-discord-server).

So to clarify, are questions about Discord on-topic for Super User? Are they on-topic for Web Applications? Or should they be on-topic for both sites?

Update: [Looks like my question got migrated...](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106450/60818)

Comment: What determines whether it's on-topic is whether the question is about a PC-based problem or a web app.  The close voters may have only been familiar with the web app and assumed that's what you were referring to.  The way to avoid that is to include details in the question that make the platform clear.  Lack of PC-based tags (like OS) may have reinforced the wrong assumption.

Comment: The reason I didn't include OS specific tags is that the question applied to *all* versions of Discord, including Windows, Mac, Linux, iOS, Android, and yes, web browser.

Comment: It looks like you gave up on this thread, which is a big waste.  The question might have confused some people as to the best home for it, but it was technically fine and the answer was great.  Consider undeleting it; it can benefit readers wherever it ended up.  You can add a few sentences to the question clarifying that it applies to any platform.  Sometimes threads get migrated to what may seem like a less ideal site for it, but people with the issue will still find it in a search.  If you feel strongly about wanting it on SU, you could ask a moderator to migrate it back.

Comment: @fixer1234 The question was deleted on Web Apps so the question could be re-opened on Super User. The migration was successfully reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems on topic to me, though to play it safe, maybe include you're running the client on some desktopish platform?

Comment: Well, the @everyone question really applies to all versions of Discord. (Desktop, bowser, mobile). Not a bad piece of advice to keep in mind for the future though

Comment: Yeah. Needed some sorting out.

Answer (score 0):

[Discord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discord) is confusing for "outsiders" because their particular use of certain words like *server* that in other contexts have different meanings.

Just in case that in 2023 might be someone wondering if a Discord question belongs to [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) (WebApps) ask yourself if the task could be done using a web browser. If you decide to post the question there, please bear in mind that there a huge chance that the first reviewers of the question will be unfamiliar with Discord and might think that the question is off-topic if it uses ambigous terms like *server*, i.e. it might be closed for being about developing / administering a web application (as computer sciences student / programmer / professional system administrator / professional software developer), so please make it clear that the question is about **using** Discord **as end-user**.

Those having enough reputation to participate on [Meta Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) might post there a question for further clarification.

P.S. As of February 5, 2023 [[discord]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discord) has only 21 questions, some of them have thousands of views.